# django - Generate a dajaxice function that validates forms (dajaxice_register issue)

Tags: python, django, decorator, introspection, dajaxice

I'd like to make a generic function to validate modelforms in real time with dajaxice.

Here is what i did :

exafeeds/ajax.py

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError                                  
from django.utils import simplejson                                                 

from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register

def gen_validate_model(models_module):

    @dajaxice_register
    def validate_model(request, model, fields):
        errors = {}

        tmp_model = getattr(models_module, model)()

        for (field, value) in fields.items():
            setattr(tmp_model, field, value)

        try:
            tmp_model.clean_fields()
        except ValidationError, err:
            errs = err.message_dict

            for field in fields:
                errors[field] = errs.get(field)

        return simplejson.dumps(errors)

    return validate_model
```

accounts/ajax.py

```
from exafeeds.ajax import gen_validate_model

import accounts.models

validate_model = gen_validate_model(accounts.models)
```

And the js call :

```
Dajaxice.accounts.validate_model(check_validity_callback, {
    'model': 'User',
    'fields': {
        'username': username,
        'email': email
    }
});
```

But when I get a JS error telling me that Dajaxice.accounts is undefined.

The dajaxice_register decorator is obviously wrong-placed, but where should I put it ?

Edit.
I tried to replace the dajaxice_register decorator with this:

```
validate_model = gen_validate_model(accounts.models)
validate_model = dajaxice_register(validate_model)
```

But it didn't change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, but it looks dirty. I would appreciate a better solution.

exafeeds/ajax.py

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils import simplejson

def gen_validate_model(models_module):

    def validate_model(request, model, fields):
        errors = {}

        tmp_model = getattr(models_module, model)()

        for (field, value) in fields.items():
            setattr(tmp_model, field, value)

        try:
            tmp_model.clean_fields()
        except ValidationError, err:
            errs = err.message_dict

            for field in fields:
                errors[field] = errs.get(field)

        return simplejson.dumps(errors)

    return validate_model
```

accounts/ajax.py

```
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register

from exafeeds.ajax import gen_validate_model

import accounts.models

@dajaxice_register
def validate_model(request, model, fields):
    return gen_validate_model(accounts.models)(request, model, fields)
```

But the function generator gets useless, so it can be simplified in :

exafeeds/ajax.py

```
def gen_validate_model(models_module, request, model, fields):
    errors = {}

    tmp_model = getattr(models_module, model)()

    for (field, value) in fields.items():
        setattr(tmp_model, field, value)

    try:
        tmp_model.clean_fields()
    except ValidationError, err:
        errs = err.message_dict

        for field in fields:
            errors[field] = errs.get(field)

    return simplejson.dumps(errors)
```

accounts/ajax.py

```
@dajaxice_register
def validate_model(request, model, fields):
    return gen_validate_model(accounts.models, request, model, fields)
```

Quite awfull :|